# Rails if else in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My comment controller needs adjust for nesting but I'm getting a few errors. Here's what I've been trying:

```
<% if @commentable == @user %>
  <%= semantic_form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
<% else %>
  <%= semantic_form_for [@user, @commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Which gives this:

```
/Users/rbirnie/rails/GoodTeacher/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end'); else
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Seems simple enough...

Here's the full view:

```
<% if @commentable == @user %>
  <%= semantic_form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
<% else %>
  <%= semantic_form_for [@user, @commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
<% end %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :subject %>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :subject %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8 %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you're free to choose template handlers, take a look at Haml (http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html) or Slim (http://slim-lang.com/). Both these languages give a chance you to forget about closing your blocks/ifs and make your templates much readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mad because the `do` bit starts a block, which expects an `end` to end it.  But when the condition is true, it finds an `else` instead.  And note that if the condition was false, it would find an `end` like it wants - but not the `end` you want!  It would find the `end` that ends your `if` statement - not the `end` that you want to end your block.

If your `semantic_form_for` blocks have different contents in each case, use Paritosh's answer.  But if they're the same code and you want to avoid repeating it, you can pick the arguments conditionally, and then pass them into a single `semantic_form_for`:

```
<% args = (@commentable == @user)? [@commentable, @comment] : [@user, @commentable, @comment] %>
<%= semantic_form_for(args) do |f|
    Whatever...
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! And it looks way cleaner than the if statement I was trying too.

Answer (score 17):

You should have a end for 'do'

```
<% if @commentable == @user %>
  <%= semantic_form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= semantic_form_for [@user, @commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It is expecting 'end' after 'do' not 'else'.

Thanks

Comment: So what is best way to solve this without needing to have the whole form_for code twice?

Comment: I am not pretty much experienced with semantic_form_for, so can't say, but any way whatever you do, one iteration will be there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're describing is plain Ruby, unrelated to view. you can write something like this instead:

```
<%
if @commentable == @user
  args = [@commentable, @comment]
else
  args =  [@user, @commentable, @comment]
end
%>
<%= semantic_form_for args do |f| %>
```